# Заголовочные файлы Linux в CLion

Tags: linux, c, clion, jetbrains

кто знает как можно подсунуть `.h` файлы линукса в CLion при написании кода на Windows, чтобы можно было переходить к сигнатурам и было меньше красного в коде?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Я такое делал только в VSCode+Clangd, но раз гугл подсказывает, что Clion тоже использует Clangd, должно сработать и в нем.

- На компьютере с виндой делаете папку, куда копируете файловую систему вашего линукса (можно попробовать удалить все кроме хедеров, но лучше пусть сначала все заработает).
- Если у вас их еще нет, в корне проекта создаете `compiler_commands.json` или `compile_flags.txt`, как описано [здесь](https://clangd.llvm.org/installation).
- В этом файле, к обычным флагам добавляете как минимум `--sysroot=папка/с/линуксом --target=платформа` (имя платформы можно спросить у `clang++ --version` на линуксе, например у меня - `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`).

Если повезет, то все будет работать из коробки. У меня сразу не заработало, но там линукс был необычный - тогда может понадобится методом тыка или добавлять флаги клангу, или патчить хедеры, пока не пропадут ошибки.

Comment: не нужно копировать "файловую систему **В**ашего линукса". Во первых, это почти невозможно, а во вторых и не нужно. Достаточно только /usr/include. Но потом нужно будет ещё и define поправить. А в целом, давно есть wsl, немного настроек и все будет работать "почти нативно"

Comment: @KoVadim У меня хедеры лежат еще как минимум в `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/*/include/`. Что-то может быть в `/usr/local/include`. Про дефайны - кажется, что `--target` должен сам проставить все необходимое.

Comment: там лежит компиляторно-зависимое. а в /usr/local/include - тут уже нужно внимательно смотреть

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59324820/2511795

Answer (score 0):

Для этого необходимо задать тулчейн, который задействуется для кросс компиляции. Это можно сделать в настройках → Build Execution Deployment → Toolchains. Как альтернативу кросс компиляции, можно использовать [Full remote mode](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/remote-projects-support.html). Однако этот режим работает хуже, чем обычный.